# puppet git access to specific module for developer

Tags: git, github, puppet

I have setup `puppet` and its working great but now i am planing to hook it up with `git` and also i want to give access to specific 1modules/files` to developer so they can change files content without accessing other modules and puppet config

I want to give access of following modules files directory to `developer`

`/etc/puppet/modules/app/files`

That way developer can checkout and check in config files inside `modules/files` folder using `git`

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really grant access to a specific directory of a git repo (that I know of).

The better route would be to use [Puppet's vcsrepo](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo) module to setup a separate git repo to house these files, which the developer could update on his/her own.  We use it for the same thing you're trying to accomplish.  Works great.

Basically what happens is the puppet master does a fresh checkout of the repo containing the files when compiling the config for a server to a directory of your choosing.  You configure the master to allow file access to the repo via puppet urls (in fileserver.conf) -- i.e. source => 'puppet:///checkedoutrepopath/files/anyfile.cfg'